# Criar const array de string em C#

Tags: c#, constantes, atributos

Há uma forma de criar um array de *string* constante?

Algo como:

```
class Teste
{
    public const string[] Array = new string[] {"a","b"};
}
```

Mas este não compila.

Neste caso *não* resolveria substituir `const` por `static readonly` por que preciso usa-lo  como parâmetro de um Atributo.

```
[CustomAttribute(Teste.Array)]
public void Metodo(){ ... }
```

Fazendo isso tenho a seguinte exceção:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Então precisa ser `const`. Há uma forma de fazer isso em C#?

Comment: Não podes usar `[CustomAttribute({"a","b"})]`?

Comment: Até da certo, mas estou numa aplicação grande e setar todos os valores na mão se torna inviável. Procuro uma forma de encapsular isso

Comment: Porque precisa ser um *array*? Porque não pode ser uma *string*? Você não pode mudar a forma de usar esse atributo?

Comment: Porque os valores que eu preciso passar são mais complexos do que isso. O fato de ser um array é para não precisar passar dezenas de strings em cada atributo. Ao invés de passar `[CustomAttribute("a","b","c","d",..."outros 20 valores")]` eu informo só o array. E se precisar alterar esses itens, altero apenas no array, e não preciso sair caçando código. Como disse antes: essa é uma aplicação grande, não posso simplesmente por uma string e deixar por isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solução

Já que um *attribute* aceita um *Type* como parâmetro (desde que este *Type* seja obtido a partir da expressão *typeof*), você pode usar a "criatividade".

Então você precisa que o *atributte* receba um array de string como parâmetro mas não deseja informar este array cada vez que decorar um membro com este *atributte*, de modo que você quer obter este array a partir de uma declaração em outro lugar, declaração esta que você pode mudar no futuro ou em um ou outro uso específico do seu *attribute*.

Para poder ter diferentes declarações do array que será passado como parâmetro para o atributo, você pode declarar uma interface:

```
interface IAttributeArgument
{
    string[] Argument { get; }
}
```

Declare um dos arrays que poderá ser usado como parâmetro do seu *attribute* declarando uma classe que implemente esta interface:

```
class AttributeArgument : IAttributeArgument
{
    public string[] Argument { get { return new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }; } }
}
```

Agora o array pode ser passado como parâmetro para o seu *attribute* assim:

```
    [CustomAttribute(typeof(AttributeArgument))]
    public void Metodo() { }
```

Na implementação do seu *attribute*, você pode criar uma instância do *Type* passado por parâmetro e ler o array assim:

```
class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type attributeArgument;

    public CustomAttribute(Type attributeArgument)
    {
        this.attributeArgument = attributeArgument;
    }
    public string[] Argument
    {
      get 
      { 
        return ((IAttributeArgument)Activator.CreateInstance(attributeArgument)).Argument; 
      }
    }
}
```

## Dica: *attributes* são declarações de metadados

Esta solução, bem como qualquer outra que você encontrar para o que deseja fazer, é uma enjambração. Veja por exemplo que o *attribute* aceitaria qualquer *Type* mas desejando receber apenas um *Type* específico (no caso, a interface), e isso é um código ruim.

Tem um motivo para *Attributes* aceitarem um range limitado de tipos como parâmetro, e o motivo é que um *atributte* é uma declaração de um metadado.

Repito: **declaração**. Decorar um membro com um *atributte* acrescenta metadados a ele que deveriam poder ser compreendidos imediatamente pelo programador sem precisar recorrer a outros pontos do código.

Ou seja, a forma ideal (expressiva) de se passar parâmetros para um *attribute* é um valor literal ou a expressão de um valor literal, como uma constante ou um *Enum*.

Um exemplo do que seria um uso expressivo de *attributes*:

```
public class LinhaLidaDoArquivoTexto
{
    [ColunaTipoData(ordem: 1, formatoData: "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    public DateTime DataEnvio { get; set; }

    [ColunaTipoDecimal(ordem: 2, formatoDecimal: "#0.00")]
    public decimal ValorEnviado { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Os parâmetros passados para o *attribute* não pretendem ser "variáveis". Eles estão ajudando a declarar, expressivamente, os metadados da classe.

Answer (score 3):

Não há uma forma de fazer isso. A única solução viável é mudar a informação.

Pelo exemplo mostrado dá para usar uma *string* simples. Se tem apenas um caractere, cada um será um elemento, se cada um puder ter mais caracteres, providencie um separador para cada *substring*. Claro, tem que tratar essa *string* adequadamente para pegar as partes. Os detalhes podem ser melhor pensados, mas é a única forma, de uma maneira geral, que conheço.

```
public class Teste {
    public const string Array = "a,b,c,d,...";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Array.cs).

Achei uma [solução para o caso de ser numérico](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121132014/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/12/03/how-do-i-create-a-constant-that-is-an-array.aspx). Note que uma enumeração deu lugar ao *array*.

Esta restrição é justamente para não permitir fazer o que deseja.

Talvez você não entenda a utilização do `const`. Quando ele é usado significa que você não deve mais alterar o valor dele em toda vida da aplicação. Claro que até pode mudar, mas teria que recompilar tudo, inclusive o que depende desta constante, o que não é garantido que aconteça. Mesmo que seja o seu caso, o compilador não irá permitir já que o CLR não permite (tem que ser possível guardar os dados no *metadata*, então não pode ter código).

Ou pode usar o *array* no próprio atributo, que não é o que você deseja, mas é uma outra forma.

Especificação:

> §24.1.3 Attribute parameter types
>
> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class
> are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> - One of the following types: bool, byte, char,  double, float, int,
>   long, short, string.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it
>   is nested (if any) also have public accessibility.
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

Comment: Não pretendo alterar este array após a compilação, até por que não há compilação. Não faz muito sentido um atributo aceitar `a Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.` sendo que gera o erro de compilação descrito na pergunta. Mas enfim, vou procurar outra forma

Comment: Ele aceita o *array*, não uma variável que é um *array*. Quando coloca o literal, ele consegue compilar e por no *metadata* o dado, quando vai usar uma variável que será inicializada, precisaria colocar o código a não ser que seja algo que não precise de código para inicializar, o que não é o caso do *array*, ele tem que usar um `new` e chamar um construtor. Ele não pode mais garantir que isto realmente é constante.

Answer (score 1):

## Solução alternativa: Enumeração

```
class Teste
{
    public enum Array = {a, b};
}
```

Assim, o trecho

```
[CustomAttribute(Teste.Array)]
public void Metodo(){ ... }
```

irá permitir a compilação.

Caso seja necessário extrair o nome do item enumerado como *string*, utilize `Enum.GetName()`.

Answer (score 1):

Se a intenção é reutilizar o valor acredito que a melhor alternativa é o uso de Herança.

Considerando o atributo

```
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
    public string[] Valor{get;set;}

    public CustomAttribute(string[] Valor)
    {
        this.Valor = Valor;
    }
}
```

Você pode criar um novo Herdando ele e passando os valores que deseja

```
public class CustomABAttribute : CustomAttribute
{
    public CustomABAttribute()
        : base(new[] {"a", "b"})
    {
    }
}
```

Então usando este novo atributo qualquer código que procure por um atributo do tipo CustomAttribute deve encontrar este novo que foi criado

```
[CustomAB()]
public void Metodo(){ ... }
```